# Changing .scrollLeft on Firefox inside the scroll event causes lag

Tags: jquery, firefox, scroll

The best way to describe this problem it to provide you with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kMPDG/

Basically, if you look at that in Chrome, as you scroll past page 2, it should start moving the whole page to the left to show page 3 that is on the right. This works fine in Google Chrome, but if you try the same example in Firefox... at the point of transition, scrolling becomes slow and sluggish.

I've tried running my scroll function through a simple function to throttle events, it worked-ish. In that situation the sluggishness was gone, but replaced with a few millisecond lag (obviously).

Have any of you guys got some advice to help me here?

```
// Code included in case jsfiddle.net fails.
$(function() {
    $('.totheright').css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: "100%",
        width: "100%"
    });
    $('#page3').css({
        marginTop: "40%"
    });

    var page2Offset = $('#page2').offset();
    var page2Width = $('#page2').width();
    var scrollFunc = function() {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
        if(scrollTop > page2Offset.top){
            var diff = (scrollTop - page2Offset.top) * 4;

            if(diff > page2Width)
                $('html, body').scrollLeft(page2Width);
            else
                $('html, body').scrollLeft(diff);
        } else if(scrollLeft != 0) {
            $('html, body').scrollLeft(0);
        }
    };

    $(window).bind('scroll', scrollFunc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
$(function() {
var page2Offset = $('#page2').position();
var page2Width = $('#page2').width();
var scrollFunc = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
    if(scrollTop > page2Offset.top){
        var diff = (scrollTop - page2Offset.top) * 4;

        if(diff > page2Width)
            $('html, body').scrollLeft(page2Width);
        else
            $('html, body').scrollLeft(diff);
    } else if(scrollLeft != 0) {
        $('html, body').scrollLeft(0);
    }
  };

   $(window).bind('scroll', scrollFunc);
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kMPDG/1/

Comment: I can't see what you changed, looks identical to mine?

Comment: i just removed $('.totheright').css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: "100%",
        width: "100%"
    });
    $('#page3').css({
        marginTop: "40%"
    });